# Enforcing type on a Razor generated hidden field, recieving variable in JavaScript with no cast

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had this passage, working and happy. Note that I'm numberizing (does it count as casting in JS?) the value being added.

```
var total = 0;
$.each($("input[blopp]:checked"), function(index, value) {
  $("#Service")[0].value += +value.attributes["blopp"].value;
  total += +value.attributes["blopp"].value;
});
$("#Service")[0].value = total;
```

The *Service* control is a hidden field generated by Razor, which based on the model provided to the ASP.NET view is of type *int*. (I suspect it's of no relevance because once on the page, we only have HTML, JS and CSS but I've been mistaken before.)

Then I started to do that thing called thinking and it wasn't very successful. The number of line got smaller, which increased readability. However, the result now isn't a sum but a concatenation of the values, because the holding variable is a string.

```
$.each($("input[blopp]:checked"), function(index, value) {
  $("#Service")[0].value += +value.attributes["blopp"].value;
});
```

My question is a simple way to type (not *to type* as in *punch on the keys* but as in *to enforce a certain type to*) the receiving variable so it knows that it's a number?

The question **isn't** about:

1. how the conversion to string occurs (it's already perfectly obvious),
2. how to numberize the receiver before the operation, i.e. *a = (+a) + (+b)* (*a += b* syntax preferred),
3. how to add a prototype to strings (it's simpler to go back to the original version),
4. how much gain there's to readability nor premature optimization (academic curiosity only),
5. how to avoid polluting the global scope (there's already IIFE around it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the one question you do want:

JavaScript does not let you enforce the target type in an operation, as anything can be any type in a weakly-typed (and not weakly as in "lightly hitting the keys" :)) language.